# Vue.js - Open Dialog for editing record

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a list with buttons to the right for each record, it looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uevzR.jpg

When I hit one of these buttons, I want a dialogue to pop up in which there are input fields like textinput, dropdowns, checkboxes etc.. This dialogue will enable to edit the respective record (and ONLY this record).
The Inputfields shall be labeled accordingly, basically each inputfield shall receive a label derived from the respective column header (see the tableheader) which the inputfield references. 
This way, the user shall know which field of the record hes applying changes to.

I'm a beginner in vue.js. I have never before used dialogues in vue.js. I know dialogues are not deemed best practice in webapplications, but its a designdecision our team has come to for several reasons and now I have to stick with it.

Our vue app is a vue-cli app. Most recent distribution. What options does vue offer me to do this? Are third party plugins or the like recommendable for this?
The dialogue might possibly display a LOT of data. It basically depends on what data the user is allowed to see. So I really need some approach which is powerful enough to handle at least low double digit number of inputoptions "ergonomically" :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the dialogue, you could use something like [bootstrap-vue's modal component](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/modal).

You can put whatever form HTML you need within the modal component.

Assuming every record in your set has the same schema, then you could have a data property e.g. selectedRecord and bind the inputs in your form to the properties of selectedRecord, then when one of your record buttons is clicked, it should populate selectedRecord with the clicked record, and show the modal.

e.g.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="record in records"
          :key="record.id">
        <span>{{record.name}}</span>
        <button class="btn btn-primary"
                @click="startEditing(record)">Edit
        </button>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <b-modal
      ref="selectedRecordModal"
      id="modal-1"
      title="BootstrapVue"
      @ok="save()"
    >
      <form v-if="selectedRecord">
        <div class="form-group" v-if="editable('name')">
          <label for="name">Name</label>
          <input type="text"
                 id="name"
                 name="name"
                 v-model="selectedRecord.name"
                 class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" v-if="editable('extra')">
          <label for="extra">Extra</label>
          <input type="text"
                 id="extra"
                 name="extra"
                 v-model="selectedRecord.extra"
                 class="form-control">
        </div>
      </form>
    </b-modal>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Vue from 'vue';
  import { BModal } from 'bootstrap-vue'

  export default {
    components: {
      BModal
    },
    data() {
      return {
        records: [
          { id: 1, name: 'record 1' },
          { id: 2, name: 'record 2' },
          { id: 3, name: 'record 3', extra: 'thing'},
        ],
        selectedRecord: null,
        user: {
          permissions: null
        }
      }
    },
    created() {
      //Replace with code for setting permissions dynamically
      this.user.permissions = {name: true, extra: true};
    },
    methods: {
      editable(field) {
        return (this.selectedRecord[field] && this.hasEditPermission(field));
      },
      hasEditPermission(field) {
        return !!this.user.permissions[field];
      },
      startEditing(record) {
        this.selectedRecord = Vue.util.extend({}, record);
        this.$refs.selectedRecordModal.show();
      },
      save() {
        //Validate this.selectedRecord and post to backend, update the original record, hide the modal etc.
        this.$refs.selectedRecordModal.hide();
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! However, while every record for a given user will look the same, the records will look different on a per user basis. The data fetched from the backend can vary in size and combination of attributes, although the basic structure will always look the same. I still require code which dynamically builds the modals inputfields as required by the data visible to the user.

Comment: btw., is the id really necessary? I fiddled around with the demo modal from bootstrap vue
https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/modal
and something really funny happened: I placed one such element "statically" at the top of my page, and I also generated them dynamically inside my v-for loop. 
They always had the "modal-1" id, and it worked. I could start the dialog when clicking the button. However, when I removed ALL the ids, nothing worked anymore. Funny thing though: As long as I left at least ONE such element with its id, the other elements which were stripped of italso worked Oo

Comment: I accepted your answer so far because it really helped me moving forward! The questions I outlined in my comments still remain though, would be nice if you could address them too! :)

Comment: @baryon123 this approach only needs one modal. I've added some extra code to show how you could dynamically construct the form within the modal based on record fields and user permissions. I also changed the startEditing function to use a clone of the original object because you don't want the original record changing if the user abandons the edit...